# Java Applet - What method gets called every frame?

Tags: java, applet, awt

I'm working on adding AWT support for my OpenGL library made with LWJGL, since LWJGL 3 doesn't support that anymore.
The way I'm doing this is by getting the screen pixels with glReadPixels and then drawing them as a BufferedImage onto a canvas.

Now my problem is that I need to update the GLFW window every frame. In an applet, is there a method I can override that gets called every frame, sort of like a game loop? Or do I have to create a custom thread for that (which would overcomplicate things, since I need to create a new OpenGL context for that)?

Here's the code for my applet so far:

```
package net.rabbit;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import xyz.rabbit.lib.framework.Window;

public class Main extends Applet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6092259155082054438L;

    private Window window;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        super.init();
        window = new Window();
        window.setParent(this);
        window.open();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("Paint");
        window.update();
    }

}
```

The Window class is my own class that handles GLFW and OpenGL specific stuff, I don't want to draw anything yet though. window.update() needs to be called as often as possible, because it handles system events.

"Paint" gets printed only twice to the console when running the application.

I'd appreciate any help, or comments on how I could solve the problem in other ways.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Because of the problems you mentioned I decided to go for a higher level approach though like I wrote above. Every frame I'm using glReadPixels to read the pixels to an int array. I'm not drawing directly to the AWT canvas, I'm just drawing to an offscreen buffer and then displaying it as a BufferedImage. That's why I need to update the image every frame. Not sure how to do that in an applet though.

Comment: I'm not using them together. My problem doesn't even involve GLFW, I could just generate a BufferedImage on the fly and render it every frame. Still doesn't solve my problem. You can use a JFrame for the problem I described and it works just fine and doesn't freeze, since I update the canvas more than 60 times a second. I now want to do the same thing with an applet. Since an applet doesn't have a main method I can't create my own game loop and therefore need a method that's called every frame.
If there's another possibility I'd happy if you share it with me.

Comment: Ok let me describe this differently. The problem I'm having is not that I don't know how to use GLFW with AWT.
Imagine that I want to create an applet that displays an image. The pixels of the image get set to a random value every frame, so that it gives me a TV like effect. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Doesn't work sadly. Repaint doesn't get called at all while running the applet. Do I need to call something to turn that on?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works.